# Execute statement have a long delay

Tags: java, sql, sybase

i have a problem. When I try to insert in Sybase some data i have long delay:

2017-11-20 20:30:10,324 [DEBUG] [] Saving data to a table

2017-11-20 21:30:28,245 [DEBUG] [] Done!

One hour, Karl!

```
String query = "INSERT INTO {0}table (id, doc_id, num_doc, amount, unload_date, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

pstmt = lib.getConnection().prepareStatement(MessageFormat.format(query, "my_schema"));
pstmt.setLong(1, id);
pstmt.setLong(2, docId);
pstmt.setString(3, numDoc);
pstmt.setBigDecimal(4, amount);
pstmt.setDate(5, new Date());
pstmt.setInt(6, 0);
pstmt.execute();
```

there are ideas why this can happen?

Comment: How much time does it take when you try to insert from command line rather than a prog? What are the health check results of DB?

Comment: Also check for other processes via sp_who whilst your insert is running and see if you're being blocked by some other spid modifying data.
 Some SQL clients may run with 'autocommit off' by default meaning they can leave locks on tables without you realizing it which could block your insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query is running slow I would recommend to check if the query is also running from an other client - like isql.

The second step would be to check if this is somewhat network related and the insert is also slow when isql is run locally.

If the query is still slow then this might be database related slow design like:

- unindexed foreign keys on columns
- slow triggers

I would run the insert with the settings

```
set statistics io on
set statement_cache off
```

And check if the number of I/O's is low. This would lead to information if a large scan is processed.

If non of the above works then you need to check which database wait event is causing the operation to be slow. Run the following code to investigate wait events:

```
select * from master..monProcessEvents where SPID = @@SPID
```

Additional MDA configuration might be required. The query would display information about which event is causing operation to go slow.